# C++ How to add message to buf in write?

Tags: c++

Iam very newbie in C++. Need help.
In C++ we have this function

```
write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t n);
write(1,str,10);
write(1,"Some string\n",13);
```

How I can combine "Some string " and str, and put this to write like this?

```
write(1,"Some string "+str,13); //like JS
write(1,"Some string ".str,13); //like PHP
```

Any way in C++?

This is Answer:
Any "+" dont work for this function.

I find right answer myself

```
 string a = "String ";
 string b = a.append((char*)&buf);
 const void* c = b.c_str();
 send(1, c, sizeof(c), 0);
 write(1, c, sizeof(c), 0);
```

Comment: What is `str` ?

Comment: any string, or buf, or any char buf. Anything

Comment: The answer will be different depending what `str` is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a c-String:

```
"Text"
```

C-Strings are arrays of the primitive datatype `char`. The concatenation-operator `+` is not available for arrays.

This is a C++ standard string (object of class `std::string`):

```
std::string("Text")
```

The concatenation operator [`+`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/) is defined for `std::string`.

Therefore you should try this:

```
write(1,std::string("Some string ")+str,13);
```

which creates a new instance of `std::string` by your given c-string. There are very few exceptions in which you have to use c-strings so always prefer

```
std::string str;
```

over

```
char[...] str;
char* str
```

Don't forget to `#include <string>`.

If you need more help about strings take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Comment: if i use this method - error cannot convert string to "const void*". I will try this many times

Comment: what is your `write`-method requiring? it youd be possible you have to convert everything back to an c-string before passing it down. `write(1,(std::string("Some string ")+str).c_str(),13);`